# How do I make it so that my PHP script goes back to my original HTML page?

Tags: php, html, css

The PHP script that's attached is able to successful send emails when the user hits the submit button. However, when the user hits submit, it redirects them to a new web page called "Mailer.php"(this is the name of the php file). I wanted to to know if there's someway that the php script can redirect users back to the html page with the submit button after they click the submit button.

```
<?php
    function alert($msgg) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msgg');</script>";
}

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $msg=$_POST['msg'];

        $to='johnsavage@gmail.com'; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID
        $subject='Personal Website Email';
        $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;
        $headers="From: ".$email;

        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            alert("<h1>Sent Successfully! Thank you"." ".$name.", I will contact you shortly!</h1>");
            header('Location: <Website Name>');
        }
        else{
        alert("Something went wrong!");
        header('Location: <Website Name>');
        }
    }
?>
```

Here's the New code I used:

```
<?php
    function alert($msgg) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msgg');</script>";
}

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $msg=$_POST['msg'];

        $to='johnsavage@gmail.com'; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID
        $subject='Personal Website Email';
        $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;
        $headers="From: ".$email;

        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            alert("<h1>Sent Successfully! Thank you"." ".$name.", I will contact you shortly!</h1>");
            $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        }
        else{
        alert("Something went wrong!");
        $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `header('Location: <Website Name>');` isn't working?

Comment: you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ` to get the previous page url

Comment: yeahh header('Location: <Website Name>'); didn't work sir. I'll try the solution you suggested now sir.

Comment: I tried replacing the header functions with`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] but those didn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: `<Website Name>` is misleading. That should be a URL, e.g. `header('Location: https://www.yahoo.com');`.

Comment: @JohnGreen Please post your exact code that you used.

Comment: Also, the <Website Name> was just a placeholder. I put in a URL in its place

Comment: you need to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` inside the `header()`. like this: `header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Mailer.php script is first outputting HTML (in this case a `<script>` tag), subsequent calls to the `location()` function won't work because HTTP headers need to be output *before* the content of the page.

You'll need to either remove the HTML output entirely, or do the redirect in Javascript:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msgg'); window.location.replace('http://www.yourwebsite.com');</script>";
```